# Determining column to use in INSERT statement based on data in the table being selected from

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to determine if I should insert data into theDate or theDate2 column based on data in the processDate column from the table being selected from. I am unable to use a column in a CASE statement however (I am getting an error when trying to run the code below), and I can't find a solution to this. How can I do this? processDate is a column from #tableTwo.

```
   INSERT INTO tableOne
       CASE WHEN processDate <> '' THEN + ',' +  theDate ELSE + ',' +  theDate2 
       END
   SELECT sDate     
   FROM #tableTwo
```

Comment: is it theDate and theDate2 tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both theDate and theDate2 can be determined by the flag processDate then do it in your select rather than in the insert. Assuming that the columns are nullable (as your CASE in the INSERT clause seems to indicate they are mutually exclusive, then I'd be inclined to do something like;

```
   INSERT INTO tableOne (theDate, theDate2)
   SELECT 
       CASE WHEN processDate <> '' 
           THEN sDate 
           ELSE NULL 
       END theDate,
       CASE WHEN processDate = '' 
           THEN sDate 
           ELSE NULL 
       END theDate2,
   FROM #tableTwo
```

Answer (score 0):

what about two queries which would look like that:

```
INSERT INTO tableOne (theDate) 
SELECT sDate 
FROM #tableTwo 
WHERE processDate <> ''
```

Followed by something like

```
INSERT INTO tableOne (theDate2) 
SELECT sDate 
FROM #tableTwo 
WHERE processDate = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax for an insert is

```
insert into table
(field1, field2, etc)
select field3, field4, etc
from somewhere
```

I have no idea if this will work, but you can try:

```
insert into tableOne
(case when processDate <> '' then theDate else Date2 end)
select sdate
from #table2
```